# LocalDate.parse for Asia/Hong_Kong, return unexpected result

Tags: java, datetimeformatter

my input is 19.12.0009,  which expect Dec 19 00:00:00 HKT 9, but the return is Dec 21 00:23:18 HKT 9, why?
the code is as follow:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu")
                        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("19.12.0009", formatter);
Instant instant = Instant.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong")));
Date resultDate = Date.from(instant);
System.out.println("resultDate" + resultDate);
```

Comment: Perhaps calendar adjustments between now and AD 9.

Comment: In this line of code in your question: `Date resultDate = Date.from(instant);` are you referring to class [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) ? Why don't you use class [java.time.ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) as in `ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong")));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ZoneRules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) there is concept of transitions, which inside have `savingsLocalTransitions`. I figured out that savings in `"Asia/Hong_Kong"` local transitions starts with `1904-10-30T00:36:42` for some reason (probably historic reasons). `ResolverStyle.STRICT` is no the issue here!

This is the reason you see `00:23:18 HKT 9`.

If you change your code, for example like that:

```java
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("19.12.1904", formatter);
```

output will be expected:

```
resultDate Mon Dec 19 01:00:00 JST 1904
```

Comment: but if I want the output exactly as what I input in string, that is, output date is  Dec 19 00:00:00 HKT 9, what can I do? I try ResolverStyle.STRICT, ResolverStyle.LENIENT, ResolverStyle.SMART but all return Sat Dec 21 00:23:18 HKT 9,
And I don't want to use ResolverStyle.LENIENT, ResolverStyle.SMART  as it will change my input "29.02.2023" also.

Comment: how to find savings in "Asia/Hong_Kong" local transitions starts with 1904-10-30T00:36:42" by code?
And the result now is Dec 21 00:23:18 HKT 9, your answer explains the 00:23:18, but not the 2 days (Dec21 c.f. Dec 19) different.

Comment: > but if I want the output exactly as what I input in string. 
maybe writing your own library extension and/or not using zones.
Note that you are using two different date/time libraries java.time and java.utils. When you are using `from(Instant instant)` it delegates call to the constructor `Date(long date)` with huge negative number, but it says that `date – the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.` maybe that a problem when mixing different libraries.